# How to export and import multi dimensional list to /from external file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to export a multi dimensional list to some external file and then later import the said list from that same external file to use in different program.

How do I go about doing this?

An example list would be something like this:

```
A=[[[1,1,1],[1,1,2]],
   [[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3]],
   [[1,3,1]]]
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be a text file, if there any file type more suitable to what I am attempting let me know.

Comment: Try [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Please mark a preferred solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `json` package. When writing, you convert the data to a json string using `json.dumps()`, then you can read the data using `json.loads()`.

```py
import json

def writeList(file, data):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))

def readList(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return json.loads(f.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # File extension can be whatever you want
    A = [[[1,1,1],[1,1,2]], [[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3]], [[1,3,1]]]
    filename = 'myfile.json'

    writeList(filename, A)
    print(readList(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest method is to just pickle the object you want to save. This is a super easy way to save and load objects in python.

```py
import pickle

A=[[[1,1,1],[1,1,2]],
   [[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3]],
   [[1,3,1]]]

# Save the object
with open('filename.pkl', 'w'):
    pickle.dump(A, f)
```

It is as easily loaded when you need it

```
import pickle

with open('filename.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    B = pickle.load(f)
```